# Как менять стиль в зависимости от выводимой даты?

Tags: php, mysql

Только начал изучать php вопрос может прозвучать не совсем корректно для более опытных.

Мне нужно сделать выборку строк по дате из таблицы базы данных и вывести данные строк в определённые div контейнер на страницу .

id | name | last_name | Date(формат даты 2019-01-20, стандартный без изменений)

вот такого типо строка в бд.

Мне нужно что бы все строки до даты(сегодня)находились в div class="box", если дата внесённая в строку сегодняшняя то строка идёт в в разметку div class="box2".

вид в размете вот таков.

```
<div class="box">
  <div>Строка с сегодняшней датой</div>
  <div>Строка с сегодняшней датой</div>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <div>Строка не достигшая сегодняшней даты</div>
  <div>Строка не достигшая сегодняшней даты</div>
  <div>Строка не достигшая сегодняшней даты</div> 
</div> 





function get_table(){

    global $link;

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `all_name` ORDER BY `priority`,`date`";

     $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

     $server = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

     return $name_list;

}
```

Вот таким методом я тяну данные из бд, это выстраивает по приоритету и дате строки, в одном.

```
`<?php foreach($$name_list as $list_part):
  <span class="icon"><?=$list_part['name']?></span>
  <span class="icon"><?=$list_part['last_name']?></span>
  <span class="icon"><?=$list_part['date']?></span>
<?php endforeach;?>`
```

вот таким методом я вставляю в html документ в div. Пытался писать непосредственно функцию а потом уже выводить одной строкой
.
 Я не знаю как написать функцию, которая будет сверять список на дату и исходя из даты выводить туда куда мне надо. Опыт в php неделя, особо не серчайте.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить вычисляемый столбец, по которому выставлять class элементу строки.

```
    $sql = "SELECT *,  ( date >= CURRENT_DATE()) as futu FROM `all_name` ORDER BY `priority`,`date`";
```

Хотя если делать в том виде, как указанно у вас в примере, те в отдельный блок, то в этот запрос надо добавить директиву `group by futu`

Пишу с телефона, потом исправлю.

Comment: По сути $sql = "SELECT * FROM `all_name` ORDER BY `priority`,`date`"; мне служит что бы упорядочить мои списки по дате и заданному приоритету. А вот как раскидать уже упорядоченные строки в совершенно разные div контейнера я  без понятия. Просто постарался снабдить всеми данными что у меня есть, что бы людям было легче посоветовать что сделать.